# Is it possible to check a token transaction history for an account with web3js?

Tags: web3js, tokens, dapp-development, dapps, javascript

If I have an account that has sent and received specific tokens, say ExampleToken (EXT), can I use web3js to see a list of EXT transfers and receipts for my address (or any other address)?

I am looking through the documentation but cannot find anything about token transaction history.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no way to list the transactions using either the **[OLD Web3.js 0.2x.x](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API)** or the **[NEW Web3.js 1.0.](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/index.html)** AFAIK, most everyone is using Etherscan's 3rd-party API.

**Example taken from their docs:**

```
http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken
```

The only alternative I know of today is to build your own custom node and record the transactions to a "standard" datastore.

Comment: Is it possible to show internal transactions? I'm getting no results for my smart contract address.